# Send emails in symfony

Tags: php, email, symfony1, swiftmailer, transport

I'm using swiftmailer (transport) in symfony 1.4.8 (and Doctrine as ORM) to send my mails.

I've configured everything as the book says.

```
dev:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      delivery_strategy: spool
      spool_class:       Swift_DoctrineSpool
      spool_arguments:   [ MailMessage, message, getSpooledMessages ]
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host: something
          port: 26
          encryption: ~
          username: something
          password: something
```

The problem is when I'm using realtime strategy , it takes too much time to send the mail and user should wait till it's done. Then the action is done and you can see the result . This is not good for me because I want to send a verification mail for user registration and if this is slow, user will fall sleep during the registration.

And I can't use spool strategy either. Because I have to send them manually with the task (am I right? ) and I can't do that too. Because it should be sent automatically after the registration.

So is there a strategy for this situation?  That is fast enough for sending emails(without need to wait until it's sent)

Comment: Yes, you need to periodically run a task if you're using the spool strategy. Why isn't it good for you? Run it via cron every 5 minutes, that should be fast enough. You can also choose to send single emails immediately.

Comment: yeah i used that too(immediately sending mails). but this strategy is too time consuming. i don't know why but it takes too much to send it. running send mail task is good too ,but i think it's not good for performance issues. is it?

Comment: Running a task every few minutes, that effectively does nothing in most cases should not be a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I send emails using a realtime strategy, and sometimes hundreds in a loop. I find that emails, especially when sent early in the sequence, are relatively quick.

I've used the following techniques:

- Gmail and SSL encryption
- SendGrid through an API
- My own API that used an email transaction table that gets swept by a task to send emails.

In my experience, a single confirmation email should be very expedient. If it isn't I would seek out other (command-line) ways to debug that transaction to see where you bottleneck is. I doubt that its PHP, Symfony or Swift.